# "Binomial" Sidon Set

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Let $[n]$ denote the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$. A subset $\mathcal{S}$ of $[n]$ is generated by randomly deciding for every element in $[n]$ whether or not it belongs to $\mathcal{S}$. The decision happens independently for every element and the probability of being added to $\mathcal{S}$ is given by $\rho$.

I am asked to show that with $\rho \ll n^{-3/4}$ we have

\begin{equation}
  P[\mathcal{S} \text{ is a Sidon set}] = 0.
\end{equation}

A Sidon set is one within which we can find distinct $a, b, c, d$ such that $a - b = c - d$.

My initial thought on this is that an approach along of the following lines might work:

\begin{equation}
  P[\mathcal{S} \text{ is a Sidon set}] = \sum_{i = 4}^n \sum_{S \subset \binom{[n]}{i}} I_{S \text{ is a Sidon set}} \, p^i(1 - p)^{n - i}.
\end{equation}

In the above equation $I$ denotes the indicator function and we split the sample space according to the amount of elements in $\mathcal{S}$. If one could show that for all $i$

\begin{equation}
  \sum_{S \subset \binom{[n]}{i}} I_{S \text{ is a Sidon set}} \leq n^{3/4}
\end{equation}

holds, the statement would follow. Establishing the above inequality, however, seems tricky.

If this is the right way to tackle the question, I would appreciate any hints on how to proceed. If not, please point me to an alternative method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First time to met this problem, let see if this argument is correct or not.

The number of distinct "Sidon quadruples" with "common difference" $i$ is given by
$$ \frac {(n-1-i)(n-2-i)} {2}$$

Therefore the total number of distinct Sidon quadruples is
$$ \frac {1} {2} \sum_{i=1}^{n-2}(n-1-i)(n-2-i) = \frac {1} {6} (n-1)(n-2)(n-3) $$

$\mathcal{S}$ is a sidon set if and only if at least one of the quadruple appear in the set. So the event of interest is the union of them, and by simple Boole's inequality, we have the upper bound for the required probability:

$$ \frac {1} {6} (n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\rho^4$$

Therefore when $\rho$ goes to $0$ faster than $n^{-3/4}$, the above bound will converge to $0$ and by squeeze theorem the probability will also converge to $0$.